# how to 'split' words entered in a text field on a form and query each word against the database

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, forms

In index.php I have a form and in the form a text field:

```
<form name="UserSearch" action="petSearch.php" method="GET">
     <input type="text" name="petWish" value="" />
</form>
```

where the user enters what pets they want into the text box (seperated by commas) e.g dog, cat, fish, snake

In petSearch.php, I use the following function to create a legal SQL string that can be used in a SQL statement:

```
<?php    
    $userPetWish = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET["petWish"]);
?>
```

I then create the SQL statement and query the MySQL database:

```
<?php
    $query="SELECT petType, name, age FROM pets WHERE petType LIKE '%".$userPetWish."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

      if($result)
      {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
             echo "From the pets you entered we have" . $row[petType] . "," . $row[name] . "," . $row[age];
          }
      }
      else
      {
         echo "Sorry we do not have any of your chosen pets in store";
      }
?>
```

So my question is:

1) In order to search for each individual pet against the database, is it possible to **'split'** the pets which the user entered by commas and then query the Pet table in the database using the "LIKE" function? If so, can you tell me how to structure this?

2) If after doing the search against the database there is a dog, cat and fish in store, but no snake. How do i get it to display this, to show the petType, name and age they have of the three pets, but not the snake? (I'm not sure if the way I structured this in the while loop is correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
explode( ',', $userPetWish )
```

to split the words up.

Also a note I would use

```
echo 'From the pets you entered we have' . $row['petType'] . ',' . $row['name'] .
    ',' . $row['age'];
```

Instead of no quotes within the $row;

Also your better of stripping the slashes strip_slashes ( $userPetWish ) if your using a LIKE otherwise your going to get slashes in the query and might break it ( may be wrong, just what ive experienced )

Comment: thanks ashley, i checked the explode function and it looks quite promising. Also why would you not use "xxxx" in the echo statement?

Comment: and what do you mean by "stripping the slashes"?

Comment: It's just better practise to use single quotes, also as the more you code the more you realise how easier it is. You don't have to perform annoying back slashes for certain things

Comment: as for stripping slashes just use $userPetWish = strip_slashes($userPetWish); after your escaping it

Comment: ok thanks. Before I try it, if the user types in a list of 50 pets, would i just need to use the same one variable `$userPetWish` when querying the database using the like function or would i need to create a for loop and create a new variable for each pet after i split/exploded it? Because when i do `....WHERE petType LIKE '%".$userPetWish."%'";` how would it know to search for each of the 50 individual pet types and not take it as one long string as a pet type?

Answer (score 0):

**1. You can try using a MATCH AGAINST query.**

```
$petArray = explode(',', $userPetWish);
$query = "SELECT petType, name, age FROM pets MATCH (petType) AGAINST ('".implode("','", $petArray)."')";
$result = mysqli_query(....
```

The result query should look like:

```
SELECT petType, name, age FROM pets MATCH (petType) AGAINST ('cat', 'dog', 'fish')
```

Please note that for this to work you should create a FULLTEXT index on your petType column. ([read more here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html))

**2. Another way to accomplish this would be with the LIKE search that you are familiar with**

```
$petArray = explode(',', $userPetWish);

$query = "SELECT petType, name, age FROM pets WHERE ";
$queryTemp = "";

foreach ($petArray as $pet) {
    if($queryTemp!=''){
        $queryTemp += ' OR '; 
    }
    $queryTemp += " petType LIKE '%".$pet."%' ";
}

$query += $queryTemp;
$result = mysqli_query(....
```